# Is there a way to extract data from Graph image and store it in Excel sheet or csv file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning

[image: This is the image of Roll angle Vs Rolling Moment.]

So is there any library in python to train such kind of images and use them for testing datasets.
I should be able to extract the X - AXIS AND Y - AXIS data and store it in csv or excel sheet.

What I tried till now :

I visited some links of Image processing for a graph in python :

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-plotting-area-charts-in-excel-sheet-using-xlsxwriter-module/?ref=rp
2. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-plotting-charts-in-excel-sheet-using-openpyxl-module-set-3/?ref=rp

I want the exact reverse of this thing. Would I be able to do it using python libraries?
Please help me out.

Comment: I have a non-python-based solution. If your goal is to extract data from graphs irrespective of using ML or python, then you should go for a digitizer. I personally use [plotdigitizer.com](https://plotdigitizer.com/).

Answer (score 9):

You could use [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/).
It's an opensource tool that let's you automatically extract data from a variety of graphs with the help of different filters/algorithms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you are going to suggest a library for OP to use, it would be helpful to give a sample of _how_ the library would help. In other words, try to solve the problem, using the suggested library, and share the code in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about this option?

```
# Importing Image from PIL package  
from PIL import Image 

# creating a image object 
im = Image.open(r"C:\\your_path\\image.png") 
px = im.load() 
print (px[4, 4]) 
px[4, 4] = (0, 0, 0) 
print (px[4, 4]) 
cordinate = x, y = 150, 59

# using getpixel method 
print (im.getpixel(cordinate))

# now plot it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(pix[x,y])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```